# Как перестать писать говнокод?

Tags: работа

Здравствуйте!
Три месяца назад меня взяли работать в небольшую организацию, для нужд которой необходимо написать приложени (под Android, пишу на Java).
На собеседовании особых вопросов не задавали. Сказали, мол, приложение будет простенькое , учиться вместе будем и тд. Руководитель мой, программист C#, он мне задания и даёт. 
Т.к. база программирования у меня крайне слабая уповаю я, лишь на гугл. Со временем, понимание начинает приходить, мозги работать. Т.е. постоянно идет работа с поиском кода, его чтением, анализом, что непонятно сразу в доки, книжки, статьи. Как то раз даже нашел в городе программиста, и напросился на встречу, где он мне написал кусок кода, который меня спас от увольнения. Даже зарегистрировался тут и на стэковерфлоу...
Но я пишу откровенный говнокод. Руководитель ругает меня за низкую скорость. И может иногда карательные меры предпринять, хоть и не смертельные. Я действительно неэффективно работаю. 
Напрашивается вывод, нужно увеличивать знания java core. И писать, писать, писать...
Но после рабочего дня, если я его честно отрабатываю, откровенно не халтуря, то мои мозги не могут воспринят информацию, в нужном объёме. Мне код снится ночью уже. Чаще мой рабочий день это 12 часов, за которые я успеваю выжать себя как лимон, потратить время на отвлекающие факторы и что то написать, вернее "*наговнокодить*". Проект двигается, разрастается и с каждым днем я понимаю, что это вавилонская башня.

Мне нужен Ваш совет, умеющие программисты. Какой то жизненный опыт, ваш. Как перестать *говнокодить*??
Спасибо!

Comment: Пойду против остальных ответов и скажу, что первый и главный шаг - осознание - уже сделан.  
И еще отдельно добавлю:

> Руководитель ругает меня за низкую скорость. И может иногда карательные меры предпринять, хоть и не смертельные.

Надо понимать, что, конечно, идеальный план не выполняется, но вина тут как минимум не на тебе одном лежит, если вообще она на тебе есть. Руководитель может тебя хоть сто раз отругать, но планирование ресурсов и построение плана входят именно в его компетенцию.

Comment: Про опыт уже написали. Добавлю только, что не переусердствуйте с работой. У человека наблюдается временные периоды активности и упадка, которые тоже влияют на работу. Недостаток отдыха и перерывов наоборот может отрицательно сказываться на работу, так как мозг еще перерабатывает полученную информацию во время отдыха без вашего прямого участия(отсюда возможны ваши сны). Если же вы будете насиловать себя в течение 12 часов каждый день, то ближе к году получите резкую антипатию и так называемый "синдром эмоционального выгорания".

Comment: @Alex Krass спасибо за коммент, полезно помнить это

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Да в общем-то никак. Умение писать грамотный код придет со временем, если, конечно же, регулярно практиковаться.  Для новичка (особенно если речь идет всего о трех месяцах опыта) говнокод и медленная скорость работы - это вполне нормальная картина. Ему просто неоткуда знать, как писать код грамотно и быстро (к сожалению этому не учат даже в институтах ). Со временем, если у новичка  есть голова на плечах и желание развиваться, он будет накапливать положительный и отрицательный опыт, научится грамотно распределять свое время и усилия, и мало-помалу этот процесс сдвинется с мертвой точки. Главные условия - это регулярная практика и самообучение. Описанная вами картина очень хорошо знакома многим (читая ваши строки, вспоминал, что почти то же самое происходило и со мной) - срывы сроков работы, регулярные баги, любовь к костылям, повсеместный говнокод, нагоняи от начальства. Серебряной пули здесь нет, это болезнь роста. Она излечивается со временем при соблюдении вышеуказанных условий.

В любом случае хорошим подспорьем будет ковыряние в чужих исходниках (Гитхаб к вашим услугшам), чтение подходящей литературы (["Совершенный код"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3159814/) Макконелла или ["Рефакторинг и улучшение существующего кода"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/)  Фаулера). Поинтересуйтесь также такой вещью, как рефактринг - изучение его принципов способно помочь в понимании того, как следует писать код. Если вы пишете на C# в Visual Studio, то великолепнейшим помощником для вас может стать Resharper. Он способен разглядеть тысячу потенциальных проблем в вашем коде и просто облегчить работу. Также очень благотворно может повлиять наличие наставника, который мог бы что-то показать и объяснить. Хотя с этим обычно сложнее.

Answer (score 8):

1. Разберитесь как правильно писать на Java: *Thinking in Java*, *Effective Java*.
2. Пишите код.
3. Читайте про хороший код: *Clean Code*, *Beautiful Code*, *Code Complete*, *Implementation Patterns*.
4. Пишите код.
5. Читайте чужой хороший код. Изучайте исходники популярных open-source продуктов. Разумеется, вы не сможете сразу отличить хорошие примеры кода от плохих. Но это даст вам пищу для размышлений и образцы для подражания (пусть даже и не лучшие). Получится своего рода бесплатный опыт: вам не пришлось тратить время на разработку и написание, вы смотрите уже на готовый код.
6. Продолжайте писать код. Перечитывайте материал из пунктов 1-3. Выкидывайте плохой код. Пишите еще. Не бойтесь рефакторить.
7. Будет отлично, если вы сможете учиться у других программистов и кто-то будет адекватно критиковать ваш код, например в рамках open-source проекта.
8. Читайте про проектирование, принципы SOLID, паттерны, тестирование. Постепенно вы научитесь отличать хороший класс от плохого.
9. Возвращайтесь к своему старому коду (даже полугодовалой давности). Обдумывайте, что в нем не так, что вы бы улучшили. Опирайтесь в дальнейшем на этот опыт.

Я это все к чему: умение писать хороший код не приходит спонтанно. Необходимо накопить некоторую критическую массу опыта только для того, чтобы начать понимать что лучше, а что хуже. Намного быстрее этот опыт набирается в среде опытных разработчиков, где вам есть с чем сравнить свой код, чем в изоляции.

> Чаще мой рабочий день это 12 часов, за которые я успеваю выжать себя как лимон

Не думаю, что оно того стоит. Такая работа - путь к стагнации и разочарованию в профессии.

> Три месяца назад меня взяли работать

А это вообще не срок. Все впереди. Главное не позволяйте работе довести себя до "творческого выгорания".

Comment: +1 Правда чтоб позволить себе так работать надо быть либо незаменимым, либо чьим-нибудь родственником. Никто не будет оплачивать развитие новичка в программиста слишком долго. Для этого предположительно уже есть годы института, возможно школы.  
"Учиться вместе будем", предполагаю, что учиться писать **под андроид** будем вместе, а не учиться писать вообще.  
Не думаю, что за такую работу стоит держаться всеми силами, боясь увольнения, финансы финансами, но здоровье дороже.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, на всякий случай я написал **"  если я его честно отрабатываю, откровенно не халтуря"**. Част бывает, что день сливается вникуда, занимаюсь непонятно чем. Конечно, в игры не играю. 
Проблема в том, что 8 часов мне не хватает, чтобы сдвинуться сместа, зачастую. Просто иногда приходится работать на износ. Ну и всеже, я хочу перерасти в программиста, поэтому я терплю. Да и все лучше, чем грузчиком работать)

Answer (score 1):

1) читать книги, если с первого раза не доходит - читать еще и еще, чтобы хорошо знать основные техники программирования и сам язык, чтобы не писать велосипеды

2) как можно больше стараться изучать чужой код (не говнокод)

3) практиковаться